# Function t is not binding correctly in latest i18next versions

Tags: internationalization, alexa-skills-kit, i18next

The code below (a localization interceptor for an Alexa skill) works fine with i18next version 10.5.0 but doesn't work in the latest versions. It get a message of function t not being recognized, it would seem t is not binding correctly.

I can't find why this is happening (I don't know what was updated in i18next). Can anybody shed some light on this?

```
// This request interceptor will bind a translation function 't' to the requestAttributes object
const LocalizationInterceptor = {
  process(handlerInput) {
    const localizationClient = i18n.use(sprintf).init({
      lng: handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.locale,
      fallbackLng: 'en',
      overloadTranslationOptionHandler: sprintf.overloadTranslationOptionHandler,
      resources: languageStrings,
      returnObjects: true
    });
    const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
    attributes.t = function (...args) {
      return localizationClient.t(...args);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like t has to be handled as a continuation in a Promise in the latest versions so here's the solution:

```
// This request interceptor will bind a translation function 't' to the requestAttributes.
const LocalizationRequestInterceptor = {
    process(handlerInput) {
        i18n.use(sprintf).init({
            lng: handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.locale,
            resources: languageStrings,
            overloadTranslationOptionHandler: sprintf.overloadTranslationOptionHandler,
        }).then((t) => {
            const attributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getRequestAttributes();
            attributes.t = (...args) => t(...args);
        });
    },
};
```